# Lazy evaluation of Fibonacci function

Tags: haskell, recursion, fibonacci

I have written the function below in Haskell and I am not too sure why it doesn't work with lazy evaluation.

```
infFib :: [Integer]
infFib = infFib' []
    where 
        infFib' [] = infFib' [0,1]
        infFib' (xs) = infFib' (xs ++ [(foldr (\a b -> a+b) 0 (take 2 (reverse xs)))])
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr because `infFib'` never returns, it only continues making calls.

I expect what you thought while building `infFib'` was roughly this:

- I want an infinite list.
- I know how the list starts, and how the list should grow.
- I'll write a function which grows the list a little bit, then iterate it.
- Oops, Haskell doesn't do iteration -- it does recursion. Okay, I'll write a function which grows the list a little bit, and recurse with it.

Unfortunately, the way you wrote it, you recurse by calling yourself with a longer and longer list -- but you never return (even parts of) that list to the caller! You just keep building a longer and longer list and calling `infFib'` on it.

What you should do instead is to start returning the parts of the list that you're confident of, and grow the parts you aren't yet confident of. For example:

```
        infFib' [] = [0,1] ++ infFib' [0,1]
        infFib' xs = newPart ++ infFib' (xs ++ newPart) where
            newPart = [(foldr (\a b -> a+b) 0 (take 2 (reverse xs)))]
```

At this point, you can test in ghci that `infFib` actually does work and produces the right answers. If this suits your needs, you could stop here and call it a day.

But this implementation is terribly inefficient compared to what's possible: here, `infFib'` is getting a longer and longer list as its argument, when it only really cares about the last two elements. It then has to walk that whole list just to get access to the elements it cares about, which wastes time and memory. Let's fix that by only passing the last two elements along. We'll have to fix up whatever function calls `infFib'` -- luckily, in this case, because it's scoped locally to a `where` block, we know there's just two, `infFib'` itself and the owner of the block, `infFib`. We'll also have to inline the base case of `[]`, since we don't have two elements to pass along yet in that case!

```
infFib = [0,1] ++ infFib' 0 1 where
        infFib' secondToLast last = [newPart] ++ infFib' last newPart
            where newPart = secondToLast + last
```

I would spend a little time thinking about how to clean this up some. I'm not sure if it's super obvious, but one thing that would make the code much cleaner would be to shift which element `infFib'` produces on each iteration to the left by two -- instead of producing the third element of the fibonacci sequence on the first call, produce the first element on the first call. This would eliminate the need for the extra `[0,1] ++` and the need for a special where block. So:

```
infFib = infFib' 0 1 where
    infFib' old new = [old] ++ infFib' new (old+new)
```

And a last one: it is very idiomatic to unroll the definition of `[x] ++ y` to `x:y`. This gives us the final definition

```
infFib = infFib' 0 1 where
    infFib' old new = old : infFib' new (old+new)
```

at which point I would be satisfied and move on to the next function I needed to write.